Можно ли сгенерировать exe файл из python, в режиме one file, но при этом, добавить в проект изображение?
Вот код. Он должен выводить изображение. Я хочу чтобы приложение .exe, сгенерированное через auto py to exe было как один, но имело внутри себя файл изображения. В самом auto-py-to-exe сказано, что так можно. Но информации в интернете я не нашёл
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk()

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.grid()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, height=400, width=700)
image = Image.open("ee.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw',image=photo)
canvas.grid(row=2,column=1)
root.mainloop()


Через additional files добавляете. При запуске exe файла его содержимое распаковывается во временную папку, оттуда уже запускается. Если дополнительный файл добавлен через additional files, он точно так же будет во временной папке, и оттуда его можно использовать.

Учитесь пользоваться поиском, сэкономили бы своё и моё время. Вопрос похож на: Автономный исполняемый файл в PYTHON. Если вы уверены что это не так, нажмите [edit], дайте ясно понять, чем ваш вопрос отличается от дубликата и/или почему ответы на него не помогают решить вашу проблему.

Ну логично же, я не нашёл решение в гугле и полез сюда
